# SharePoint Online - Infopath 2010 filler form - not opening in IE browser

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, browser-enabled-form

I have an Infopath 2013 form, compatibility form type is "infopath 2010 filler form".

In my library(SharePoint Online), in Library Settings ---> Adv Settings---> I have the setting

"Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents: Open in the browser "

In a page, I have a CEWP with an anchor tag , link to open the template :

```
/teams/SiteName/SubsiteName/LibraryName/Forms/template.xsn
```

At admin centre, the infopath form services settings is to allow browser enabled.

But still, when clicked on the button, Form does not open in browser.

I have made all possible settings for this by searing over the internet.

I am getting below error:

```
This form cannot be opened in a Web browser. To open this form, use Microsoft InfoPath.
```

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can try, and in the past I have often found that it ends up being voodoo of some type or other that finally get's it working but some of my hard/fast rules were to

1. Make sure that not only the library where you're forms will be stored, but also the "Form Templates" library is set to specifically "Open In The Browser", not default even if that is "Open In The Browser"
2. Make sure, in InfoPath Designer, Form Options, Compatibility you've set the form type to "Web Browser Form" and entered the valid URL to the server that will be hosting your form.  Also, make sure "Allow code to use features that work only when filling forms with InfoPath Filler" is unchecked.
3. Make sure you run "Design Checker" BEFORE you publish... this tests it against the URL you set in #2, and will give you a warning if anything in your form is keeping you from being able to use the browser.  If that passes then you should be good to go.

All this said, I admit that it's often flaky and you sometimes just have to monkey with it.  But it should tell you when publishing if the form is good to "Open in the Browser" if it says that and then still asks to open in InfoPath Filler then it's just having issues picking up the settings in the libraries.  Or at least that's been my experience.

Good LUCK!

Comment: Thank You for the response! Referring to your 2nd point,  If compatibility is of type "Infopath filler 2010", then will the form not be opened in browser?

Comment: In Internet Explorer, when we browse the form path, - It asks us to "Save" or "Save As" instead of opening the form. Any suggestions here?

Comment: Re user63217, that's correct, you must specify that it's a "Web Browser Form", regarding IE, if it's asking you to "Save" or "Save As" then it isn't a web browser form, it's trying to open it in filler (I think)... unless I've misunderstood.